# Show that: $\Pi_{i=1}^{n}(v_{i}) > \Pi_{i=1}^{n}(u_i) \rightarrow\Pi_{i=1}^{n}(v_{i} \cdot w_{i}) > \Pi_{i=1}^{n}(u_{i} \cdot w_{i})$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-writing

Didn't fit in title but $u, v, w \in ({\rm I\!R}^{+})^{n}$

How would I go about proving this,

I know that:

$x > y \rightarrow x \cdot z > x \cdot z, x,y,z \in {\rm 
I\!R}^+$ .

But how can I extend this to this product?

Comment: [Your question should be clear without the title](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/42969). After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. The title is not the first sentence of your question, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title.

Comment: you can just divide through by $\prod_{i=1}^n w_i$ on both sides